# Using a function to give values for parameters in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Can you use a function, define them as values and then use it in parameters.
Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def design_standard()

    height = 25
    width = 25

    return width, height

root = tk.TK
root.title("Test")

test.label(root, text ="Test", design_standard())
```

and what would happen is that the label "Test" would have width = 25 and height  = 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of.  The key is to understand that calling a function isn't anything special.  The function returns something, and calling the function is the same as writing that something.  So, what you wrote is the same as writing:

```
test.label(root, text="Test", (25,25))
```

And for a Tk label, that won't work.  You CAN do it by returning a dictionary, although I'm not sure it's really worthwhile:

```
def design_standard():

    height = 25
    width = 25

    return {'width':width, 'height':height}

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")

test = tk.Label(root, text ="Test", **design_standard())
```

The `**` operator here "converts" a dictionary into named parameters.

Comment: There is typo: `tk.TK` should be `tk.Tk()`.  And missing trailing `:` in `def design_standard()`.

Comment: Hmm, I just cut-and-pasted his code without reading it closely enough.

Comment: would it just be better to Define the height and width and etc as a variable, at the start of the code?

Comment: That's a personal preference.  If those are fixed constants, then I would just define them at the top.